# Uncaught ReferenceError: showimage is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call function to show uploaded image preview when user uploads it, When I use it for specific DIv ID, it works fine but when I tried to make a universal function, it is giving me the error of uncaught reference error everytime I upload the file.

My code is as follows.
Java Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function showimage (v) {

    $('#'+v).change(function () {

        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var value = v.value;    
            var dvPreview = $("#dvPreview");
            dvPreview.html("");
document.getElementById(v).innerHTML = "mycontent";
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
            $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                var file = $(this);
                if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = $("<img />");
                        img.attr("style", "height:100px;width: 100px");
                        img.attr("src", e.target.result);
                        dvPreview.append(img);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                } else {
                    alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                    dvPreview.html("");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
 <input class="myinput" id="img1" onchange="showimage(img1)" type="file" name="profile_image" value="Browse.." />
  </p><div id="dvPreview"> </div> </td></label>
```

Any Idea what is the problem???

Comment: Take it out of `$( ... );`?

Answer (score 0):

Include the javascript code before the DOM is loaded. This should work.
Include it at the end of body tag or in the head section (if the javascript code is small and there are no chances of bugs)

Comment: Thanks Sir, But sir our script is already defined in head section.

Comment: Please share a plnkr if possible.